# Can't append carriage return

Tags: java, android

I am building a serial communication app for my android phone and when I read the responses from the java buffer I cant get the responses to have a carriage return at the end of each one. Here is part of the code.

```
public void handleMessage(Message msg)
{
if(iavailable > 0)
{
    readText.append(String.copyValueOf(readDataToText, 0, iavailable));

}
}
```

readDataToText is the bytes from the buffer and iavailable is the amount of bytes. This was converted earlier in another piece of code from byte to char. When I send the system status command I am supposed to get something like this back:

```
:000000037D
```

If I send the command 3 times I get:

```
:000000037D:000000037D:000000037D
```

but I want to get

```
:000000037D
:000000037D
:000000037D
```

I have tried too many different codes to remember and I have spent too much time on this to the point I am blocked. I am new to java, been learning for about 2 weeks. I used to code in TCL/TK and there are some similarities but I get lost too much. I have search this forums but I have not found the correct answer or maybe I have just not implement it correctly. So far I have tried:

```
String readText = System.getProperty("line.separator");
readText.append("\r\n");
```

And many more but still no help. When I use any of these other lines all I get is spaces at different intervals between mu response but it is still all in the same line.

Comment: Where is your output going?  And unless you have separators within the serial data, there may be no way for the app to know where to put line breaks.  **Do not assume** that a serial interface API will provide data in chunks of a desired size in any way aligned to the size of buffers handed to the sender.

Comment: Sorry for my delay but I was away without access to the pc where I have the code. My output is going to a EditText widget field. The way I read the data from the device is issuing the read(byte[]data, int length) command. ftDev.read(readData, iavailable); is used in the code then readDataToText[i] = (char) readData[i]; to convert the bytes into char and then it is used in the code above to create the string that finally is presented in the field. Hope that was what you were asking.